# Forge SharePoint Online Integration

Tags: authentication, autodesk-forge, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am following Forge SharePoint Online Integration [text](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/sharepoint-online-integration) but receiving an error for newly added step "http Get Signed URL".

The new "file-url" is  below and I with this I get the error of only bucket creator can access this bucket (adam_sharepoint/objects/). I am on the impression using "Post" on this step we are creating a bucket so I changed "adam_sharepoint/objects/" to something else but I received the error bucket doesn't exist

concat('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/adam_sharepoint/objects/', triggerOutputs()?['body/{FilenameWithExtension}'],'/signed?useCdn=true&access=write')

I guess my question is how to create a bucket using post method on Power Automate for this SharePoint online integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLWrf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I own **bucket** `adam_sharepoint` and only I have access to it.

You need to create your own **bucket** and use that for the **SharePoint** integration.

You can simply use a utility like [Buckets Tools](https://oss-manager.autodesk.io/) or [VS Code Extension](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/forge-visual-studio-code) to create your own **bucket**.